# explanations of some of context-bound words

Tags: vocabulary

From his closest friend, Horatio, Hamlet learns of an extraordinary **visitation** that took place the night ***before***. Horatio witnessed the **marching** ***by of*** a fearsome apparition-- surly no flesh-and-body creature-- but rather some sprit or ghost in ***the very image of*** the late king arrayed in battle armor.

Would you please throw a light on especially the bold parts?

I am wondering what is **by of**, the very image of, marching, and visitation?

Although I have looked up all the vocabulary in dictionaries, in fact, I am wondering what some of them could mean-- the bold parts.

Comment: It's "the [ marching by ] of [ a fearsome apparition ]" and "the [ very image ] of [ the late king [ arrayed in battle armor ] ]".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I linked the collins dictionary for you:

- [visitation](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/visitation?showCookiePolicy=true): See 4: an appearance or arrival of a supernatural being -> seeing a ghost
- night [before](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/before?showCookiePolicy=true) : See 1: earlier than the time when -> the previous night.
- (the marching [by](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by?showCookiePolicy=true)) of (a fearsome apparition): See 15: adverb: passing a point near something -> walking past him
- the very [image](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/image?showCookiePolicy=true) of : See 1: a representation or likeness of a person or thing -> a gost looking like the dead king.